# Retrieving Single json object in Array

Tags: angularjs, json, api

I am stuck trying to retrieve a single json item from an array to from my $http get.

I have tried using scope, and a few other methods- but none work.

The json object/data appears (in the Chrome network inspector) and my directives in my HTML are correct.

How can I get Angular to understand a give a single item in a json array to a directive?

My object looks like this:

[{"id":1, "name":"test1"}]

```
function productsApiProvider($http, $stateParams) {

    var product_id = $stateParams.product_id;

    var getApiData = function () {
        return $http.get(BASE_URL + product_id);
    };
    var BASE_URL = 'http://123.com/api/item/';

    return {
        getApiData: getApiData
    };

}


function ProductsCtrl($scope, $log, productsApi, UserService) {
    $scope.product=[];
    productsApi.getApiData()
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data)) //Shows log of API data
            $scope.products.unshift(result.data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            $log.error(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: What does the `result.data` look like? Are you try to retrieve a single item from the API or to performance a filter function by passing the `product_id`?

Comment: Is `result.data[0].name` value "test1" is that what you need here for the object `result.data[0]`

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$scope.product.unshift
```

not

```
$scope.products.unshift
```

notice the "s" at the end of product.

Comment: This didn't work for me. But result.data[0].name did work as suggested by  Mark Schultheiss

Answer (score 0):

Adding as answer from comments so it can be accepted, closing this out.

`result.data[0].name` value "test1" is that what you need here for the object `result.data[0]`